# Find a file from current directory

Tags: python, file, printing

I want to find a file from current directory the executable is running, say -

```
delta001.png
```

if it does not exists then print it.

If it exists then print -

```
delta002.png
```

The name of the file to be printed is 'delta' but the number would be the next number which is found in the directory. The number could be anything like - '112', 334, 234, 087 etc.
  Python 3 or higher.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will find any files that start with `delta` where delta is followed by numbers:

```
import glob

print(glob.glob('delta*[0-9].txt'))
```

The `.txt` can be changed to whatever extension you need. It can even be changed to a `*` to find all files that match that format regardless of extension.

`glob` returns the files found to you in a list so you can then iterate over the list if you need to append the file names to a URL or create a list of their complete path.

Comment: He also needs to use something like `os.path.exists("delta.png")` to check if the file exists or not

Comment: Will glob find things that aren't there?

Comment: Ok, this seems to be working fine. I can't up vote, sorry, my rep is low and just lost one :). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Surely this would suffice?

```
import os

for i in range(1,1000):
    if not os.path.exists("delta{}.png".format(i)):
        print "delta{}.png didn't exist".format(i)
```

Edit, it starts at 1 and goes up to 1000 (delta1.png, delta2.png...etc you'll want to change it so it's 001, 002...etc)

Comment: Thanks @p99will, didn't spot that when I wrote it.

Comment: :D, Thanks. Only problem is knowing if this works for Python 3 `Python 3 or higher.` As it think OP wants. I don't know anything about Py3.

Comment: Seems like it works, but in my case looping 999 times is not a good idea. It makes the application unresponsive. Thanks.